# Copy objects with messages between interaction diagrams

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

I have 2 Interaction Diagrams in my project. How can I move or copy objects from one diagram to another BUT including messages between selected objects? I'm using EA 9.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must have been my mistake. I can just copy (ctrl-c) objects from one diagram and on another diagram "paste as new" and all messages are preserved.